# Which layout can provide free drag and drop insertion?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using Eclipse graphical layout, and i want to Drag and Drop components to the layout and i want them to stay at the exact position that i dragged them.

Relative Layout is the closet thing but it changes the location of the components after couple insertion.
thanks.
Rami.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually absolute layout is the answer what u want ,but that is deprecated.Relative layout does what you want.But it arrange its child based on parent position.If you drag a text view ,then other view will depend on this text view.If you have inserted 2 view,then third view will depend on the parent(2 views).But in between if u disturb any of the view ,it may affect other views.So do things systematically

Answer (score 5):

> i want them to stay at the exact position that i dragged them.

No, you don't. Android devices come with screens in many different sized and resolutions, so fixed positioning of components is a recipe for making the application unusable to users with a different screen that you.

The point of layouts is that they can adjust to different screen sizes. Learn to use them properly.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for AbsoluteLayout, but it is deprecated.

RelativeLayout is the way to go, just pay some attention to the hints drawed on-screen when you place your elements.

You should be careful also to avoid circular references otherwise your items will be scattered randomly over the layout. (Example: Textview A on right of TextView B; TextView B on left of TextView A)

Be careful also when you change your element's id because the IDE does not update automatically all the references and thus your layout gets scattered again. When you update an ID you must update all its references in the XML file by hand.

Answer (score -1):

In Java what we can typically use is [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html). You may see what the equivalent is for android.

Comment: even if android is java-based, not all the classes are available. Specifically, layouts are handled quite differently in android than in regular java